# How to create a Chrome extension that provides an application icon in the dock to open a website in app mode?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I create a Chrome extension that:

- provides an application icon in the application menu and on the desktop
- on click of the icon launches a particular website in Chrome's application window mode

Comment: that would be an app not an extension. your q needs to show more effort (what have you researched and tried so far? what didnt work?) or this can be flagged or closed.

Comment: @ZigMandel I will have a look at Chrome applications and their difference to extensions. Can you please leave this open? I will edit my question and provide more information of my own research. Thank you!

Comment: I havent voted yet :) you will find that the user will need to create the desktop shortcut by right-clicking the app in the chrome apps page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.management` API to the rescue. You can create a website-type app programmatically with [`chrome.management.generateAppForLink`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-generateAppForLink).

Please note that the API has an undocumented restriction, it has to be called from a [user gesture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab#invoking-activeTab).

---

The closest you get to create an icon on the desktop/dock is `chrome.management.createAppShortcut`.

> Display options to create shortcuts for an app. On Mac, only packaged app shortcuts can be created.

This automatically highlights 2 caveats:

1. It does not do so silently, it shows a dialog to the user
2. In case of OS X, website apps are not eligible

Note that your app will still automatically appear in the Chrome's App Launcher.